# Custom font not rendering while click on select menu (dropdown)

Tags: css, google-chrome, custom-font

I have add custom font(font-family: 'verbmedium') for my layout. If i am clicking select menu while drop down rendering unwanted charactors(please see the attached picture) after selecting which is coming finely.[image]

Comment: I am facing this issue only in Chrome

Comment: Mmm, show your html, do you have the meta charset tag? <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: Does the font work for normal content? Where does the font come from, and what code (HTML and CSS) do you have in order to use it?

Comment: Post the form code and the css being used. You can't just declare a custom font without proper css import or other methods.

Comment: I have added  font-family: 'verbmedium'; for body and added same for select. Instead of this not any other style used. Verb font i have converted as webfont using by http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ site

Comment: There are several fonts distributed under the name “Verb Medium”.

Answer (score 0):

Check webpage font encoding

try manually substituting the webpage's encoding. Follow these steps:

Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
Select Tools. --> Select Encoding.

Pick one of the encodings listed or choose Auto detect.

If you choose to auto detect, Google Chrome analyzes the content on the page to recommend the most suitable encoding. For the fastest browsing experience, turn off the auto detect mode after you leave the webpage.

You can also change the preferred fonts and languages used to load your webpages.

[READ](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en)